# Vim: need a function to switch to an active buffer by name

Tags: vim, buffer

Say I have a terminal buffer open on some window with needed buffer dimensions etc.
I'd like to switch to the window where it is opened with a hotkey. 
I can make it with some big 'Denite' plugin:

```
function! FocusBufOrDo(arg,cmd)
  if buflisted(bufname(a:arg))
    " exec 'buffer ' . a:arg
    exec 'Denite buffer -default-action=switch -mode=normal -immediately-1 -input=' . a:arg 
  elseif !empty(a:cmd)
    " echo 'No such buffer'
    exec a:cmd
  endif 
endfunc

nnoremap <Leader>c :call FocusBufOrDo('/usr/bin/bash','term')<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>gi : call FocusBufOrDo('gist:','tabe \| Gist bf39XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX5')<CR>
```

Now I want a dedicated function to do the switch. 
Tselectbuffer or tlib plugins have that functionality but I am not able to rip it out. Would be very grateful when you do it for me =)

Comment: Works for me as is. I opened 2 files, X and Y, switched to buffer X and run `:buffer Y` — vim switched to the buffer with the named file.

Comment: phd, I want to go to the window where it is opened already; edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
" Run through the list of buffers,
" match buffer's filename with the argument,
" switch to the 1st window, if found.

function! GotoWindowByFileName(name)
   for b in getbufinfo()
      if b.name =~ a:name
         call win_gotoid(b.windows[0])
         return
      endif
   endfor
endfunction
```